# Async API having 91K Records

Tags: mysql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a Locality Model having about 91K Records in it.
My Locality Model has only 3 Fields: id, name & city_id
I am Joining it with Cities Table to differentiate the almost similar names from the Locality Table

```
$data = Locality::query()->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'localities.city_id')->select('cities.id as id', DB::Raw("CONCAT(localities.name, ', ', cities.name) AS localityCity"))
->orderBy('localities.name')
->when($request->search, fn (Builder $query) => $query->where('localities.name', 'like', "%{$request->search}%"))
->when(
    $request->exists('selected'),
    fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereIn('localities.id', $request->input('selected', [])),
    fn (Builder $query) => $query->limit(10)
)
->get();
```

This Code works fine when I am using it to add new locality
but when the api has already selected data then it is showing Too Many Request Error and when I disable the throttle and try again it takes too much time to select the data

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The code you've shared does not use any "Too Many Request Error". Also, is this a MySQL problem or a PostgreSQL problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should optimize your query. Did you try creating table index? You can also try to retrieve the records with the chunk method. Take a look at the chunk method for your Laravel version.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results